# Obtaining the mean and standard deviation of normal fitting

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram, distribution

I have to distributions p and q I have no knowledge about their mean and variance I want to fit a normal distribution curve to the histograms I have and get the mean and variance of the fitting

when I use

```
histfit(p);
histfit(q);
```

I get the results in the figure:
[image]

when I use

```
[f,x]=hist[p];
[mu,sigma]=normfit(p)
pdf=normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
figure;
hold on
bar(x,f);
plot(x,pdf);
```

I get the results in the figure where I don't see the fitting at all:

[image]

Eventually I would like to present graphically histfit,
,but also obtain **the true standard deviation and mean of the fitting** for further use.

help anyone?

Comment: Simply [deleting and reposting an identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284394/obtain-mean-and-variance-from-normal-distribution-fitting) is not the right way to deal with questions you don't like.

Comment: Downvoting 10 of my questions just because I mentioned this is a dupicate neither...

Comment: my friend I have deleted my previous questions and published a legitimate question that have much more information and insight from the previous ones that were not clear. also, my question follow all the requirements of stackoverflow. You are BOTHERING ME. unless you wish to participate in the discussion about the fitting please leave me alone and stop harassing me with your posts.

Comment: The one who upvoted this (@Daniel ?) Any way to report/undo that? I could not find a flag on a user page

Comment: @A.Visser: I see the timing and it is suspicious, but according to the profile info there are only 7 upvotes recorded (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420894/jarhead?tab=topactivity)

Comment: @Daniel, I guess re-earning my rep is the way to go then. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @Daniel A.Visser, please remove your comments from this post. they interfere with the discussion

Comment: OK, NOW THAT THIS ISSUE IS CLEAR, HELP ANYONE?

Comment: @Stewie Griffin, it has hold on, the values of the fitting is very near zero so you don't see it ( notice a green and black line around the zero of the y axis)

Comment: This line looks strange, what is it supposed to do? `[f,x]=hist\[p];` I get a "Not enough input arguments"

Comment: @Stewie Griffin ,it's quite large and used for research so I can't...I think this is something technical with the normalization or the definitions of histfit , I can't seem to find a way to work it out for a couple of days

Comment: @Daniel, type error, thanks, corrected

Comment: @Daniel, this is usually how I save the histogram data if I then wish to normalize it by f/sum(f)

Comment: Also: when I do : mean(p) and std(p), I get the same values for the normfit, so I guess these values are correct however I can't seem to present it graphically

Comment: Do you want to display the full curve or just the text? `text` allows you to visualise text on a plot.

Comment: Please double check your code, there is still a syntax error in it.

Answer (score 1):

What `histfit` does is plotting a pdf *normalized* to the scale of the histogram. A scaling factor of `numel(p).*mean(diff(x))` is applied to match the curve with the histogram. It scales the area under the pdf to the area the histogram covers.

Comment: Yes, there is an explanation. The total area of a histogram is the number of counts `numel(p)` multiplied by the bin width (here computed as `mean(diff(x))`, which is not necessarily optimal). The total area of a pdf is 1. To match both, either the histogram values have to be divided by `numel(p).*mean(diff(x))` or the pdf values have to be multiplied by that value. See also [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/169064/17023) on stats.SE (but ignore the comments by some a... who basically claims that Matlab's histograms are not histograms according to some definition).

Comment: Thx, put parts of your comment into my answer.